# Django's LoginView uses old username attribute even with a custom User model

Tags: python, django

I wanted to customize Django's builtin authentication system to replace username with email (i.e. use an email/password combination instead of a username/password combination for login), so I made a custom `User` model by subclassing `AbstractBaseUser` and `PermissionsMixin` and a custom `UserManager`, then set `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'` to enable it.

Everything works fine, but the problem is, the login form as generated by `django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView` uses `name="username" type="text"` and label id `id_username` for the email input field (in spite of using the correct label string "Email address"). The login form works regardless, but it's wrong semantically and the HTML5 client-side validation doesn't work this way. Note that this isn't a problem in the registration form; it names the email field as `email` rather than `username`, as expected.

Here's the code:

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from .managers import UserManager


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False)
    verification_code = models.CharField(_('verification code'), max_length=32,
                                         blank=True)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        '''
        Return first_name plus the last name, with a space in between.
        '''
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        '''
        Return short name (first name) for the user.
        '''
        return self.first_name
```

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        '''
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        '''
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

settings.py

```
...
# Redirect to my URL after login
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

# Custom login backend (using email instead of username)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.User'
...
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),
        {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/verify/(?P<code>[a-zA-Z0-9]{32})$', views.verify,
        name='verify'),
]
```

views.py

```
...
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

from . import util
from .forms import RegistrationForm

...
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.verification_code = get_random_string(length=32)
            user.save()
            res = util.send_verification_email(request, user)
            if not res.ok:
                logging.error(res.text)
                return HttpResponse(status=500)
            return render(request, 'registration/registration_complete.html')

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    token = {}
    token.update(csrf(request))
    token['form'] = form

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', token)


def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        return LoginView.as_view()(request)
...
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

from .models import User


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'John',
                                                 'autofocus': 'true'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Doe'}),
            'email': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':
                                            'johndoe@example.com'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.pop('autofocus')
```

Templates generate the form using a for-loop on `{{ form }}`.

I realize that I'm using a custom registration form as defined in `forms.py`, but I have no idea how to do the same with the login form and I couldn't find anything online or in the docs.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why you're using LoginView at all. Logging a user in is [just a few lines of code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) and is perfectly easy to do in your own view.

Additionally, it's really not good practice to call a view directly from another view.

But if you really want to use the LoginView, you need to subclass AuthenticationForm and then pass that form class into the LoginView call:

```
return LoginView.as_view(authentication_form=MyAuthFormClass)(request)
```